# How do I delete a graphic in LyX

Tags: lyx

This sounds like a joke question but it is not.  I have inserted a png file without putting it in a float. It is not in the middle of any text but appears between a latex code float figure and a subsection header. Delete and backspace affect the surrounding material but skip over the graphic. If I click on the graphic it opens the file selection dialogue box.  Selecting cancel does nothing.  If I delete the filename I can no longer select ok.  I cannot see a way to remove the graphic. I am using 2.07 for Mac.

Comment: To state the obvious (but maybe it isn't obvious here), delete and backspace both ought to work. The only thing that comes to mind is that the graphic is not in the location it appears to be, but I don't know why that would happen. Perhaps try using the mouse to create a selection starting before the graphic and finishing after it, and delete the whole lot.

Comment: I have tried all those things and they don't work in this case.  I found another way - enter an invalid graphic filename, then LyX gives an error and the filename appears in a box which I can delete.  Previously it appeared as a graphic.  I still suspect I am missing something.

Comment: Sounds like a glitch to me. :-)

Comment: This is either a faulty install, a corrupt .lyx file, or a bug in LyX. It would be great if you could provide an example that would help us fix this bug. see http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample  . Also, consider upgrading to LyX 2.0.8.1 (and possibly 2.1.1 although this would lead to bigger changes).

Comment: I am trying LyX for the first time, and this happened on the first figure I inserted. The trick of changing the filename to something bogus and then deleting worked for me. I am using LyX 2.1.2-2 in Debian 8.2 (squeeze).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is likely about a bug in LyX. Better to make an example (if possible) and report it at http://www.lyx.org/trac/